# Filter integer list in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-expression, spring-expression-language

I am learning about [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org) in Spring, and I am struggling with list fitlering.

The official [Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#some-more-pages-for-our-grocery) does not talk about collection filtering and projection, but I found out that Thymeleaf on Spring uses the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

This guide states the following:

- The syntax of the selection (filtering) operator is : `${collection.?[property == value]}`
- The syntax of the projection (mapping) operator is : `${collection.![property]}`

This is fine if I have a list of objects, for example a list of persons. Then I can perform things like that:

- Selection (filtering): e.g., `${persons.?[age >= 18]}` selects all persons of at least 18 years
- Projection (mapping): e.g., `${persons.![name]}` selects the name of every person

---

Question:

What if I do not have a list of objects (such as a list of persons) but a list of numbers or list of Strings? How can I perform selection (filtering) then? Things like `numbers.?[>10]` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more search, I found the answer in the [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) documentation.

In *10.5.11 Variables* the documentation states the `#this` and `#root` variables.

> The variable #this is always defined and refers to the current evaluation object (against which unqualified references are resolved).

So, assuming I have a list `numbers` filled with integers, `${numbers.?[#this >= 10]}` creates a new list that contains all numbers that are at least 10.